# Why isn't the Flask-Login current_user.is_authenticated consistent?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have an Angular app that is making API calls to the backend Flask app. The Flask app is using Flask-Login to authenticate users when they login. When the user logs in with the `login()` function I defined, `current_user.is_authenticated` returns `True`. When I call another function called `get_is_logged_in()`, `current_user.is_authenticated` returns `False`.

My `User` class inherits from `UserMixin`, so it has all of the required properties and methods as explained in the documentation (https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class). In the `login()` function, after calling `login_user()`, I checked `current_user.id` to verify that the proper user is being logged in. I also checked `current_user.is_anonymous` and it returned `False`, as expected.

user.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Text, Integer
from flask_login import UserMixin
from .database import Base, Session

class User(Base, UserMixin): # Inherits UserMixin
    __tablename__ = "USER"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(450), unique=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    password = Column(Text, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, email, first_name, last_name, password):
        self.email = email
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.password = password
```

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import pymssql

db_url = "DB_URL"
db_name = "DB_NAME"
db_user = "DB_USER"
db_password = "DB_PW"
engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pymssql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_url}/{db_name}')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_user, login_required, 
logout_user, current_user
from .entities.database import Session, engine, Base
from .entities.user import User

import json    
# Other necessary imports

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return Session().query(User).filter_by(id=user_id).first()

@app.route('/api/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    try:
        posted_email = request.json['email'].lower()
        posted_password = request.json['password']
        user_json = get_user_by_email(posted_email)

        if not bcrypt.check_password_hash(user_json.get_json() ['password'], posted_password): # The password was incorrect
            return jsonify(success=False, message='The password is incorrect')
        else: # The login was successful, so pass in all user credentials (except password)
            # Get user object from the database
            user = load_user(1) # Hard-coded id for testing

            # Login the user
            login_user(user, remember=False, force=True)

            return jsonify(
                success=True,
                user=current_user.is_authenticated # Returns True
                )
    except KeyError: # A KeyError is only thrown if the user does not exist
        return jsonify(success=False, message='A user with that email does not exist')

@app.route('/api/isLoggedIn', methods=['POST'])
def get_is_logged_in():
    return jsonify(success=current_user.is_authenticated) # Returns False when called
```

Notice that I am using the declarative base from SQLAlchemy. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
return jsonify(
        success=True,
        user=current_user.is_authenticated # Returns True
        )
```

This will always return true because you're explicitly setting `success = True` regardless of the value of `current_user.is_authenticated`

I don't see you calling `get_is_logged_in` anywhere, but the most obvious reason for it returning false is because `current_user.is_authenticated` isn't actually equal to `True` when the function is being called, thus you're setting `success` to false.

A code snippet of you calling `get_is_logged_in` would be helpful to know for sure.

Comment: In Angular, I'm using a guard to check if the user is logged in whenever the user tries to access the "main page." The line that calls the function looks like this: `return this.http.post<isLoggedIn>(this.ROOT_URL + '/isLoggedIn', {});`. As for the `success=True`, that success is referring to a successful login. The `user=current_user.is_authenticated` is `True`, but when the Angular guard calls `get_is_logged_in()`, it returns `False`, but I'm expecting it to be `True` because the `login()` function is called beforehand. I'm sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the `current_user` is not being persisted between requests, especially if your methods of calling `/api/login` and `/api/isLoggedIn` vary.

The `load_user()` function will run for each request so you might find it helpful to check the `user_i`d it is loading each request (i.e. add a print statement).